# How to change the route in component did mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, routes, components

I am using this code in render to display the heading. Need to move this logic to mount event. How to achieve this.

```
  render() {
     const viewPage = this.props.history.location.pathname.includes("/app/accountManagers/view/")
     const editPage = this.props.history.location.pathname.includes("/app/accountManagers/edit/")
     const newPage = this.props.history.location.pathname.includes("/app/accountManagers/new/")


        return (<div >
                <div className="app-wrapper">
                    <ContainerHeader match={this.props.match} title={<IntlMessages id={editPage ? "DIC_ADMIN_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_MANAGERS_EDIT_MANAGER" : newPage ? "DIC_ADMIN_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_MANAGERS_NEW_MANAGER" : "DIC_ADMIN_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_MANAGERS_VIEW_MANAGER"} />} />

                </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use Routes instead of matching location

Comment: based on the route need to change heading in my index page. so i had used this logic

Comment: So this component isn't rendered on one of the above routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
componentDidMount(){

    const viewPage = this.props.history.location.pathname.includes("/app/accountManagers/view/")
    const editPage = this.props.history.location.pathname.includes("/app/accountManagers/edit/")
    const newPage = this.props.history.location.pathname.includes("/app/accountManagers/new/")

    return(
            <div>
                    <div className="app-wrapper">
                            <ContainerHeader match={this.props.match} title={
                                    <IntlMessages id={editPage ? 
                                    "DIC_ADMIN_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_MANAGERS_EDIT_MANAGER" : newPage ? 
                                    "DIC_ADMIN_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_MANAGERS_NEW_MANAGER" : 
                                    "DIC_ADMIN_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_MANAGERS_VIEW_MANAGER"}
                                     />
                                     }
                             />
                     </div>
             )
}
```